# python and javascript with html generation

Tags: javascript, python

On a website that I manage, we have JSON files which contain page data. We then create the page using this JSON.

The data looks roughly like this (except a lot more complex).

```
[
  {"title": "Hello world", "content": "World, hello to you!"},
  {"title": "Hello world Part II", "content": "The sequel to hello world."},
  ...
]
```

This data is then parsed into HTML. Now, here lies the issue: we need two versions of the HTML.

One needs to be static, outputted in the format of `file-0.html` which would be formatted with a title of `Hello World` and content of `World, hello to you!` and `file-1.html` (title=`Hello World Part II`, content=`The sequel to hello world`).

The second needs to be just a plain page `file-all.html` which includes a JavaScript that pulls the JSON via AJAX when its needed and creates a container for each page which includes subpages that have the content/titles for everything in the JSON.

Right now, we use Python to generate the HTML for the `file-0.html` static pages, and then JavaScript for the AJAX pages. While this works, it means there is a lot of code duplication for a pretty small project—every time we want to change the class of the `<h1>` title is wrapped in, we have to change two places with slightly different syntax.

Is there any good way of fixing this issue, so that all the code for generating page (or as much as possible) is in one language? (This would probably have to be JavaScript, since bandwidth is an issue—we'd like to avoid transferring `HTML` via AJAX if possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two good options:

- Write the page generation logic in a template language like Mustache (http://mustache.github.com/).  Then you can compile those templates down to Python (for the server side) and Javascript (for the client).  The data consumed by both versions is the same and you only have to maintain one template definition.
- Write everything in Javascript and execute that JS on the server.  There are at least two good server-side JS engines: V8 and Apache Rhino.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the server to render the page and grab that with an AJAX response. While this avoids code duplication, it might be less efficient since you have to query the server to render each page, rather than making the client do it themselves (this might not be too much of an issue, though). It shouldn't take up too much bandwidth, since it's just HTML (unless you're throwing in templates from all sorts of places). This approach, of course, only works if you're using a dynamic web site.

Alternatively, you can implement all the rendering logic in JavaScript and use something like [PyV8](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/) to run it from within Python. I question the efficiency (and sanity) of this, though.